# silverlight control hosted in mfc activex webbrowser control does not get key input

Tags: silverlight, mfc

We have a MFC Dialog with the Microsoft Web Browser activex control for displaying web pages. When a page contains silverlight you cannot type into the silverlight text box. It seems as though mouse and command messages make it to silverlight but not the wm_keydow/wm_keyup

refrance to the microsoft connect issue https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536872/silverlight-3-cannot-type-in-textbox-when-running-in-microsoft-web-browser-object

Answer (score 0):

Workaround 1 - alter the html object for the Silverlight application to be "windowless":

```
<object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
                             <param name="source" value="webConnectSilverlightApplication.xap"/>
                             <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                             <param name="background" value="white" />
                             <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
                             <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                             <param name="windowless" value="true"/>
                             <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50826.0" style="text-decoration:none">
                                             <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
                             </a>
                </object>
```

Workaround 2 - override PreTranslateMessage in WebViewer dialog class to override the bug:

```
BOOL CMFC_WebViewerDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
     if (pMsg->message == WM_CHAR)
     {
             DispatchMessage(pMsg);
             return true;
     }

     return CDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

The probable cause

> The problem is the ActiveX control
>   doesn't own the message pump. The
>   message pump is owned by the container
>   application. Therefore, all the
>   keystroke messages are taken by the
>   container application and not
>   dispatched to the modeless dialog box
>   or propertysheet window.
>
> The problem does not occur with a
>   modal dialog box/propertysheet window
>   because the message pump is owned by
>   the dialog box manager, and it takes
>   care of handling all keystroke
>   messages.
>   Blockquote
>   source http://support.microsoft.com/kb/187988